# adding CPLEX to Julia

Tags: julia-jump

I have tried to add the CPLEX to Julia but it didn't work, can anyone help me to figure out what is the issue. the version of Julia and CPLEX  are 1.4.2 and 12.10.

````
julia> Pkg.build("CPLEX")
   Building CPLEX → `C:\Users\Asus\.julia\packages\CPLEX\rmvSt\deps\build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `CPLEX`: 
│ INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
│ ERROR: LoadError: Unable to install CPLEX.jl.
│ 
│ The versions of CPLEX supported by CPLEX.jl are:
│ 
│ * 12.10
│ * 20.1
│ 
│ You must download and install one of these versions separately.
│ 
│ You should set the `CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES` environment variable to point to
│ the install location then try again. For example (updating the path to the
│ correct location if needed):
│ 
│ ```
│ ENV["CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES"] = "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\ILOG\\CPLEX_Studio201\\cplex\\bin\\x64_win64\\"
│ import Pkg
│ Pkg.add("CPLEX")
│ Pkg.build("CPLEX")
│ ```
│ 
│ See the CPLEX.jl README at https://github.com/jump-dev/CPLEX.jl for further
│ instructions.
│ 
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
│  [2] try_local_installation() at C:\Users\Asus\.julia\packages\CPLEX\rmvSt\deps\build.jl:112
│  [3] top-level scope at C:\Users\Asus\.julia\packages\CPLEX\rmvSt\deps\build.jl:130
│  [4] include(::String) at .\client.jl:439
│  [5] top-level scope at none:5
│ in expression starting at C:\Users\Asus\.julia\packages\CPLEX\rmvSt\deps\build.jl:123
└ @ Pkg.Operations D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:899

julia>
````

Comment: did you try the instructions in the error message?

Answer (score 2):

a) Do not use Julia 1.4.2. Please update to the latest Julia version (1.6.3) or use the Long-Term-Support (Julia 1.0).

b) Follow the installation instructions: https://github.com/jump-dev/CPLEX.jl#installation

c) If you have CPLEX 12.10 installed, The path won't be `CPLEX_Studio201`, but something like `CPLEX_Studio_1210`